# Select elements of an (n,n,2) numpy array with an (n,n) shaped mask in numpy without using loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a (n,n,2) numpy array whose elements I want to select based on a (n,n) mask without using loops. Is there a way to vectorize this operation in numpy? Say I have a numpy array

```
X = array([[[18,  8],
        [ 9,  2],
        [11,  4],
        [18, 14]],

       [[ 8, 10],
        [13,  5],
        [13,  6],
        [13, 18]],

       [[ 8,  4],
        [ 2, 13],
        [19, 11],
        [ 3, 15]],

       [[12,  6],
        [ 7,  3],
        [19, 17],
        [ 1, 12]]])
```

and a mask

```
M = array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 1, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 1, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Treating each 2-D entry in X as one element, is there a way to use the mask M to select elements of X? That is, select the 2-D element in X if its corresponding element in the mask M is 1.

So the example above will return

```
[
 [[18,  8]],
 [[ 8, 10],
  [13,  5]],
 [[19, 11]],
 []
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [393]: I,J = np.nonzero(M)                                                                  
In [394]: I,J                                                                                  
Out[394]: (array([0, 1, 1, 2]), array([0, 0, 1, 2]))
In [395]: X[I,J,:]                                                                             
Out[395]: 
array([[18,  8],
       [ 8, 10],
       [13,  5],
       [19, 11]])
```

It was pointed out that you don't just want these elements, you want them grouped by row.  To do that, a list comprehension does nicesly:

```
In [407]: [x[m.astype(bool)] for x,m in zip(X,M)]                                              
Out[407]: 
[array([[18,  8]]), array([[ 8, 10],
        [13,  5]]), array([[19, 11]]), array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=int64)]
In [408]: [x[m.astype(bool)].tolist() for x,m in zip(X,M)]                                     
Out[408]: [[[18, 8]], [[8, 10], [13, 5]], [[19, 11]], []]
```

Yes that uses a loop, but that's what you have to expect when getting a list of variable size items.

`vectorized`, no-loop solutions only work with regular array results.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can just use: print(X[M==1])